# Solution explorer in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Can anyone tell me how to open the solution explorer tool in qt creator (the toolbar where the source files , header files , etc. are shown) ? I have closed it accidentally and now I can't find where to enable it again .

Comment: Window -> Show Sidebar?

Comment: Thanks a lot ... the solution was ridiculous :D